# Apache CXF 3 not generating address element

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I upgraded my CXF from 2.7.11 to 3.1.0 version and now the WSDL is being generated without the address element inside port element.

CXF 2.7.11:

```
<wsdl:service name="CoffeeRequestDocumentManagerWebService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:CoffeeRequestDocumentManagerWebServiceSoapBinding" name="CoffeeRequestDocumentManagerWebPort">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:80/api/CoffeeRequestDocumentManager"/>
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

CXF 3.1.0:

```
<wsdl:service name="CoffeeRequestDocumentManagerWebService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:CoffeeRequestDocumentManagerWebServiceSoapBinding" name="CoffeeRequestDocumentManagerWebPort">
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

I saw that class HTTPTransportFactory does not implement interface WSDLEndpointFactory anymore (it implements in 2.7.11) which generates the AddressType on HttpEndpointInfo extensors so I created a custom DestinationFactory that calls HTTPTransportFactory.createEndpointInfo(...) but it's still not generating the element.

Comment: Please explain it a bit more. May be show us comparison between wsdl or code change in those versions.

Comment: I put the difference in service part of WSDL, just the address element is missing.

Comment: It sounds like a bug in CXF, please file a JIRA here with a sample WSDL: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF